# Celery - Check if worker received SIGTERM

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a `Celery` task that is quite long. More than a few minutes.

Sometimes, for various reasons, a worker is marked for termination and another worker starts. This can happen if the machine it runs on needs to be replaced, or a new code version is being deployed. In that case, the worker receives the SIGTERM signal.

I'm wondering if it's possible for the task itself to periodically check whether this worker has received SIGTERM and is pending termination, and in that case just put the task back in the queue and terminate. (The task will then be started on another worker, and will continue doing its work)

EDIT: Clarifying - Is it possible within the task to check whether it is executed on a worker that waits to be terminated. Like this:

```
# Some long task that can take even a few hours.
def some_task(...):
    for i in range(...):
        do_some_work()
        # That's the missing function:
        if did_this_worker_received_SIGTERM_and_waiting_to_be_terminated():
             # stop the task in the middle, and it will be executed again later
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Celery worker receives SIGTERM, it will initiate the *warm shutdown*. It means it will unsubscribe itself from all the queues, prefetched tasks (if any) will go back to their queues, and worker itself will start waiting for the currently running tasks to finish before it shuts down. No task is lost, if that is what you fear.

All these events can be handled (see [Worker Signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-signals)).

If you still insist on having some extra logic inside your tasks that handles worker state, then perhaps the easiest solution is to implement worker shutdown handler (as described in the doc section I mentioned above), make it store a flag in Redis or some other distributed K/V storage), and refactor your tasks that need this so they access this flag and perform whatever action you need them to perform.

Comment: I will edit the question later to make it clearer. But the question is whether the task itself can check whether the worker it is running on is in the warm shutdown flow

Comment: It is simple, handle the signal, and store a flag somewhere (worker's config for an example) so that task can check the flag and do some internal handling... I humbly believe tasks should not do this, instead let the worker re-queue them, or similar...

Comment: Config will not work... Redis is probably the best option. I've updated my answer with this approach.

Comment: I am not receiving the `worker_shutting_down` signal at all when container shuts down. Running celery via docker on AWS ECS. Any clues? I am directly running `celery -A ...` as `CMD` in docker so I assume it should get the signal isn't it?

Comment: Update: It turns out you need to use `["bash","-c","celery -A ..."]` as the `CMD` to get signals coming to your celery worker within Docker. I hope this helps folks trying to do this in Docker. I struggled with tini and other init programs just to realize bash is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why do you want to do such a thing? did you enable `task_acks_late`? That way, if a task won't finish on time and the worker will go down, the task will rerun again on a new worker.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-late). There's also [task_reject_on_worker_lost](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-reject-on-worker-lost) which I didn't try, but maybe it can help you as well:

> Setting this to true allows the message to be re-queued instead, so
> that the task will execute again by the same worker, or another
> worker.

Comment: The problem with ack_late is that it needs to wait for the completion of the timeout. So if the task has a timeout of 60 minutes, but after 2 minutes it needs to be terminated, then ack_late will put it back in the queue only 58 minutes later. But if the task can detect that it is terminating, it can just put it back in the queue already

Comment: Can you elaborate how do you define and use the timeout?

Comment: I define it by the length of the task. For example if I know that some task takes ~60 minutes, I will define the timeout as 70-90 minutes

Comment: with `task_time_limit`? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_time_limit